# Android calendar app crashes after creating a new event

Tags: android

I am adding a new event to the calendar using this piece of code.

```
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Events.DTSTART, event.getStartTime());
    values.put(Events.DTEND, event.getEndTime());
    values.put(Events.TITLE, event.getSubject());
    values.put(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, event.getLocation());
    values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, event.getDescription());
    values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, calendarId);
    values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
    Uri uri = cr.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

When the piece of code runs it doesn't seem to error at all. However when I open the calendar using the default Android calendar app, it crashes when I try to view the added event.

Logcat comes back with this error

```
01-15 21:57:24.091: E/AndroidRuntime(19125): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: 
unknown error (code 0): Unable to convert BLOB to string
```

I would imagine that I am doing something wrong when entering the event. Any ideas?

Edit:

This is the dump of the values

01-15 22:39:47.561: I/System.out(25804): Values: calendar_id=2 eventLocation=fndn title=dndbdb dtstart=1421386255183 dtend=1421389801672 description=fnfbd eventTimezone=America/New_York

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937983/sqliteexception-unable-to-convert-blob-to-string-when-contact-have-photo-androi?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: I have looked at that. I wasn't able to get much from it because that was referring to updating an existing contacts. I am adding a new event from scratch.

Comment: post more code - the `put` method allows for all data types. so you are apparently putting a BLOB where a string is expected

Comment: What other code should i post?

Answer (score 0):

Code is correct for adding event. To resolve the issue, either put all the source code or put break point for debugging to analyze where the issue is rising. As far as my knowledge, you are trying to save some thing in sqllite database after event or before event placing and that is where error is occurring because the value you are passing is not according to the datatype defined for the variable in database.