# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unknown error (code 0): Unable to convert BLOB to string

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am getting this error while updating name in existing contact. My code:

```
String nameWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "='"
            + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'";

String[] idParam = new String[]{contacts.getContactId()};

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, id);
    values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, contacts.getName());
    int update = context.getContentResolver().update(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, values, nameWhere, idParam);
```

I have also go through these links:
[SQLiteException Unable to convert BLOB to string when contact have photo. Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937983/sqliteexception-unable-to-convert-blob-to-string-when-contact-have-photo-androi)
and other related to that problem.

and my logs

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.embedded.contacts, PID: 15248
                                                                       android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unknown error (code 0): Unable to convert BLOB to string
                                                                       #################################################################
                                                                       Error Code : 0 (SQLITE_OK)
                                                                       Caused By : unknown error (code 0): Unable to convert BLOB to string
                                                                       #################################################################
                                                                       #################################################################
                                                                       Error Code : 0 (SQLITE_OK)
                                                                       Caused By : unknown error (code 0): Unable to convert BLOB to string
                                                                       #################################################################
                                                                       Error Code : 0 (SQLITE_OK)
                                                                       Caused By : unknown error (code 0): Unable to convert BLOB to string
                                                                       #################################################################
                                                                       #################################################################
                                                                           at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:179)
                                                                           at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
                                                                           at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.update(ContentProviderNative.java:568)

Comment: Show full logs...

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I have added the logs, check again.

Answer (score 0):

your code is modifying two values: `RAW_CONTACT_ID` and `DISPLAY_NAME`.
Problem is `RAW_CONTACT_ID` is read-only.
I'm assuming you don't intend to modify the raw-contact-id anyway.
If you just want to modify a contact's `DISPLAY_NAME` by its ID, try this:

```
String selection = Data.CONTACT_ID + "=" + contacts.getContactId() + " AND " + Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'";
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, contacts.getName()); // make sure getName() returns a String!!!
getContentResolver().update(Data.CONTENT_URI, values, selection, null);
```

(verify you import the correct classes of `Data` and `StructuredName`)

Comment: I have also tried by removing `RAW_CONTACT_ID` update but my problem not resolve.